# Setting the volume of a torus with integral

Tags: calculus, integration

The disk in the $xz$ plane with center at $(x,z) = (R,0)$ and radius $r$ $(0< r < R)$ is rotated about the $z$-axis to generate a torus in $R^{3}$. Setup the integral to determine the volum of the generated torus. Slice the circle in narrow band and rotate those about the $z$-axis

the band are of height $2\sqrt{r^{2}-(x-R)^{2}}$ and thus a volume of

$$\Delta V = 2\pi x \cdot2\sqrt{r^{2}-(x-R)^{2}}\, \Delta x$$

This leads to the total volume

$$V = \int_{R-r}^{R+r} 2\pi x \cdot 2 \sqrt{r^{2}-(x-R)^{2}}\,\mathrm dx = 4\pi \int_{R-r}^{R+r} x \cdot2 \sqrt{r^{2}-(x-R)^{2}}\,\mathrm dx$$

using $u = x-R$ we get : 
$$V = 4\pi \int_{-r}^{+r} (u + R) \sqrt{r^{2}-(u)^{2}}\,\mathrm du \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

And then we get

$$V = 2\pi \int_{-r}^{+r} R\cdot2 \sqrt{r^{2}-(u)^{2}}\,\mathrm du \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

$$V = 2\pi R \cdot\pi r^{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

What I don't understand is how we get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ and $(2)$ to $(3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)\to(2):$ $u\sqrt{r^2-u^2}$ is an [odd function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Basic_calculus_properties), which means
$$\int_{-r}^r u\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,\mathrm du=0.$$
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
V=4\pi\int_{-r}^r (u+R)\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,\mathrm du&=\underbrace{4\pi\int_{-r}^r u\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,\mathrm du}_{=0}+4\pi\int_{-r}^r R\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,\mathrm du\\
&=2\pi R\int_{-r}^r 2\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,\mathrm du.
\end{align*}

$(2)\to(3):$ Notice $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ is a semi-circle above the $x$-axis with radius $r$. If we consider the geometric meaning of the integral, the following integral is exactly the area of a circle with radius $r$:
$$\int_{-r}^r 2y\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-r}^r 2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\pi r^2.$$
Therefore,
$$2\pi R\int_{-r}^r 2\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\,\mathrm du=2\pi R\int_{-r}^r 2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=2\pi R\cdot\pi r^2.$$